# PHP SERVER superglobal HTTP_USER_AGENT key undefined with file_get_contents request

Tags: php, user-agent, php-5.3

I am making a call from my local development environment to a URL on one of my test systems with the following code:

`$vnumber = file_get_contents($url);`

On *one* of the environments I get this error below, however on all others I do not experience this.

> Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in
>   /var/www/vhosts/test/crmpicco.co.uk/web/config.php on line 127

Line 127 is this:

`define ("USER_AGENT", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

Other than the `$_SERVER` superglobal being accidentally trashed (which I cannot find) what would be a potential cause of this?

I am using PHP 5.3.27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had `error_reporting(E_ALL);` switched on with my broken environment.

I turned that off and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

And how can it be set? You're doing direct `file_get_contents()` call, while `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is set by *browser* which is absent it this scenario. To emulate HTTP request in full way, use [`cURL`](https://www.php.net/curl) in PHP (so [`curl_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) with `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`)

Comment: Yes, I understand the use of cURL and file_get_contents however this code is working on all other environments so my question was more around what could be the problem? All environments are on PHP 5.3.27.

Comment: My only guess is that in other environments your errors displaying is turned off, so you can't see an error while it's present

Comment: Thanks for that, that is exactly what it was. My broken environment had `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Do you want to submit an answer?